# SSIS: i need to populate 2 Excel spreadsheets from 2 different queries inside For Each Loop

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I am creating multiple xl files from ssis package. I assign dynamic file name to each workbook in the For Each Loop in the FileSystemTask where I copy a blank template from template directory to the output directory where all few hundreds Excel files need to be output. Part of the file name comes from the values in the loop.
Each file has 2 spreadsheets. Different SQL Query is a source for each.  When I output files with 1 spreadsheet filled it is no problem. However, when I add the second source-destination or another data flow i get an error that connection string is in invalid format or other...  Should I use second set of OLEDB Source/ Excel Destination within same data flow or use another data flow for second spreadsheet?

Comment: You definitely have two different destinations and since you are trying to process them simultaneously then I suggest 2 connections. You will only need one source since it is the same DB with different queries.

Comment: I also assume you are building both file names based on the loop variable. You definitely need one variable to hold the loop variable and 2 more to hold the file names for the connection string

Comment: yes! it works! thanks.

Comment: now i m dealing with this issue: not a big deal but curious how ssis processes data flows:https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/2012639/Data-Flows-with-2-or-more-SourcesDestinations

Comment: If you are preventing locks that is your problem. try to rearrange the data flow to *not* do these simultaneously by choosing one data flow to run first and then the second.